# Can I get the bookmark button back into the bookmarks bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I usually had a bookmarks button in my bookmarks bar to  have quick access to those bookmarks that did not fit into the bar itself. Since Firefox 23, it is not displayed anymore, only the bookmarks remain. To get access to the bookmarks button, I have to move it into the navigation bar or the addon bar.

Is there a way to enable it again? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I as can see the Firefox's **Bookmark button** will show up if you have the **Menu b
Bar** hidden.

Sou you can try the following.

### Disable the global menu and Hide the Menu Bar to enable the button.

**1)** Open Firefox and type about:config in the address bar, then click to confirm in "I'll be careful, I promise"

[image]

- Search the key "ui.use_unity_menubar" and select it , then double click to change the value from true to false

[image]

**2)** Right click in the firefox window and "uncheck" Menu Bar.

[image]

After that you should have the Firefox Button instead the menubar, and the Bookmarks button will appears.

[image]

Then Right click and select **"Customize.."** to drag the Bookmarks button from you Navigation Toolbar  to your Bookmarks toolbar.

[image]

Finally you can go to "about:config" and enable the "ui.use_unity_menubar" key to display the unity global menu.

### Firefox addon.

Install the following addon named *Classic Bookmarks Button*.

**1)** Install the [Classic Bookmarks Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicbookmarksbutton/) and restart Firefox.

**2)** Right click and select **"Customize.."**.

[image]

- Drag the **Bookmarks Button** to your Navigation or Bookmarks Toolbar.

[image]

In Navigation Toolbar:

[image]

Or in Bookmarks Toolbar:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works both ways. After using and comparing it for a while, I'm preferring the first method. Thnaks a lot!